# Why can't I use a null pointer in an if statement?

Tags: c, list, function, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to do a simple homework with lists and I want to code a function that:

1. Receives a double pointer to the head of a list and an integer
2. Checks if the head is pointing to something or NULL
3. If the head points to NULL, then reassign it to a new memory location containing my new node [etc.]
4. If not null, just add the new node to the bottom of the list

However I receive a "read access memory violation" when my code checks if the head list is NULL or not;
This is my code:

```
void InserList(t_node** lis, int x) {
    t_node* temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(t_node));
    temp->num = x;
    if (*lis == NULL) {
        temp->next = NULL;
        *lis = temp;
    }
    else {
        temp = *lis;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(t_node));
        temp->next->num = x;
        temp->next->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

My code runs without problems until it has to do this:

```
if (*lis == NULL) {
        ...
 }
```

Giving me an error "**lis was nullptr**".
Is my idea wrong? How should I fix this function?

Thank you

**EDIT**: This is the main function

```
int main(void) {
    int elements;
    int count;
    int tempnum;
    t_node *head, *second_head;
    head = second_head = NULL;
    t_node **ref_head, **ref_second_head;
    ref_head = &head;
    ref_second_head = &second_head;
    scanf("%d", &elements);
    for (count = 0; count != elements; count++) {
        scanf("%d", &tempnum);
        InserList(head, tempnum);
        if (IsPrimo(tempnum) == false) {
            InserList(second_head, tempnum);
        }
    }
    PrintList(second_head);
}
```

Comment: And how did you call `InserList`? That's where `lis` comes from, after all

Comment: `if(lis == NULL)` no need to dereference (depends on how you manage it)

Comment: `lis` itself is a pointer, why don't you check it first?

Comment: Show the code that calls `InsertList`, the problem is most likely there.

Comment: head should initialize to `NULL` at caller side. Also `temp = *lis;` occurs memory leak.

Comment: When question is missing information, people start guessing what the problem is. Please read and provide [mcve].

Comment: can you give the compilation error log you are getting ?

Comment: The error is:
Exception thrown: read access violation lis was nullptr

Comment: `InserList(head, tempnum);` --> `InserList(&head, tempnum);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why you should compile with warnings. Here's what you do:

```
InserList(head, tempnum);
```

You pass a `t_node *` where a `t_node **` is expected. Those are incompatible pointer types. Your program thus has undefined behavior.

Fix *that* to be:

```
InserList(&head, tempnum);
```

Then give your compiler high level warning flags and fix your code until it's warning free.

Comment: Thank you, I have also realized that I made "ref_head" and "ref_second_head" just for this but I didn't use them, what an idiot am I.
Thank you again